# Can't validate inputs with "required" attribute

Tags: html, forms, input, required

I have an HTML form, which consists of few divs, and there are label and input inside every div.
So for name and email inputs I want to add "required" property. But when I set it and then submit the form, I instantly start running the form action, even if my inputs were empty. So that's first time I face with such a trouble. It's also the first time when I put divs inside the form, but it seems like it should work anyway.
So you can see my code below:

```html
<section>
  <form id="feedback_form" method="POST" action="{% url 'feedback' %}">
    <div class="field half first">
      <label for="name">Name*</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="field half">
      <label for="email">Email*</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="button submit" type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: I converted your code into a live demo and cannot reproduce the problem. Clicking the submit button triggers a "Please fill in this field" alert and blocks submission.

Comment: Are your browser autofilling the fields perhaps? Try in a private mode window or try another browser.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this. It was an issue with some implicit javascript code on page (I usually work with backend, so haven't made this page by myself before).
So in .js file I found such part of script which disallowed submitting form in a standard way.

```
$('form').on('click', '.submit', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```

So my advice: if you work with code written by others, do some more research and check files few times if you can't solve some implicit tasks.